# MYSQL PHP Matching numerous comments to the correct status in social network activity feed

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if any of you could help as I have been stuck on this for days.

This is the first time I have tried writing a query on this scale.

I am creating a social network and am doing the query for the activity feed which shows when people have liked something, commented on something etc. I have it all working apart from when somebody replies to a status.

What I want to do is attach the relevant comment to the relevant status which kinda works but it shows duplicate entries of the original status. Please see the query below

```
SELECT
                d1.d_id AS d1_d_id, d1.profile_picture AS d1_profile_picture, d1.username AS d1_username, d1.forename AS d1_forename, d1.surname AS d1_surname,
                d2.d_id AS d2_d_id, d2.profile_picture AS d2_profile_picture, d2.username AS d2_username, d2.forename AS d2_forename, d2.surname AS d2_surname,
                d3.d_id AS d3_d_id, d3.profile_picture AS d3_profile_picture, d3.username AS d3_username, d3.forename AS d3_forename, d3.surname AS d3_surname,
                d4.d_id AS d4_d_id, d4.profile_picture AS d4_profile_picture, d4.username AS d4_username, d4.forename AS d4_forename, d4.surname AS d4_surname,
                a.ra_id AS ra_id, a.r_id AS r_id, a.comment AS a_comment, a.type AS a_type, a.status AS status, a.date_posted AS date_posted,
                ar.r_id AS ar_r_id, ar.comment AS ar_comment, ar.type AS ar_type, ar.status AS ar_status, ar.date_posted AS ar_date_posted, 
                c.slug AS cat_slug,
                p.p_id AS p_id, p.title AS title, p.slug AS slug,
                m.media_path AS p_media_path,
                m1.i_id AS m1_i_id, m1.media_path AS m1_media_path, 
                m2.i_id AS m2_i_id, m2.media_path AS m2_media_path,
                m3.i_id AS m3_i_id, m3.media_path AS m3_media_path,
                m4.i_id AS m4_i_id, m4.media_path AS m4_media_path
                FROM activity AS a
                INNER JOIN designers AS d1 ON d1.d_id = a.d_id
                LEFT JOIN media AS m1 ON m1.i_id = d1.profile_picture
                LEFT JOIN projects AS p ON p.p_id = a.r_id
                LEFT JOIN media AS m ON m.i_id = p.image
                LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON c.c_id = p.c_id
                LEFT JOIN designers AS d2 ON d2.d_id = p.d_id
                LEFT JOIN media AS m2 ON m2.i_id = d2.profile_picture
                LEFT OUTER JOIN designers AS d3 ON d3.d_id = a.t_id
                LEFT JOIN media AS m3 ON m3.i_id = d3.profile_picture
                LEFT JOIN activity AS ar ON ar.r_id = a.ra_id
                LEFT JOIN designers AS d4 ON d4.d_id = ar.d_id
                LEFT JOIN media AS m4 ON m4.i_id = d4.d_id
                WHERE a.status != 1 AND a.type != 'Follow'

                UNION

                SELECT
                d1.d_id AS d1_d_id, d1.profile_picture AS d1_profile_picture, d1.username AS d1_username, d1.forename AS d1_forename, d1.surname AS d1_surname,
                d2.d_id AS d2_d_id, d2.profile_picture AS d2_profile_picture, d2.username AS d2_username, d2.forename AS d2_forename, d2.surname AS d2_surname,
                d3.d_id AS d3_d_id, d3.profile_picture AS d3_profile_picture, d3.username AS d3_username, d3.forename AS d3_forename, d3.surname AS d3_surname,
                d4.d_id AS d4_d_id, d4.profile_picture AS d4_profile_picture, d4.username AS d4_username, d4.forename AS d4_forename, d4.surname AS d4_surname,
                a.ra_id AS ra_id, a.r_id AS r_id, a.comment AS a_comment, a.type AS a_type, a.status AS status, a.date_posted AS date_posted,
                ar.r_id AS ar_r_id, ar.comment AS ar_comment, ar.type AS ar_type, ar.status AS ar_status, ar.date_posted AS ar_date_posted, 
                c.slug AS cat_slug,
                p.p_id AS p_id, p.title AS title, p.slug AS slug,
                m.media_path AS p_media_path,
                m1.i_id AS m1_i_id, m1.media_path AS m1_media_path, 
                m2.i_id AS m2_i_id, m2.media_path AS m2_media_path,
                m3.i_id AS m3_i_id, m3.media_path AS m3_media_path,
                m4.i_id AS m4_i_id, m4.media_path AS m4_media_path
                FROM activity AS a
                INNER JOIN designers AS d1 ON d1.d_id = a.d_id
                LEFT JOIN media AS m1 ON m1.i_id = d1.profile_picture
                LEFT JOIN projects AS p ON p.p_id = a.r_id
                LEFT JOIN media AS m ON m.i_id = p.image
                LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON c.c_id = p.c_id
                LEFT JOIN designers AS d2 ON d2.d_id = a.r_id
                LEFT JOIN media AS m2 ON m2.i_id = d2.profile_picture
                LEFT OUTER JOIN designers AS d3 ON d3.d_id = a.t_id
                LEFT JOIN media AS m3 ON m3.i_id = d3.profile_picture
                LEFT JOIN activity AS ar ON ar.r_id = a.ra_id
                LEFT JOIN designers AS d4 ON d4.d_id = ar.d_id
                LEFT JOIN media AS m4 ON m4.i_id = d4.d_id
                WHERE a.status != 1 AND a.type = 'Follow'
                ORDER BY date_posted DESC
```

I have tried going down the route of grouping by the tables comment id but thus makes only the status and one comment show in the feed.

I am using a table called activity which then has a column called type which will have entries such as 'Status', 'Status Reply' 'Like' etc. and has a column called r_id (not the unique id), when you reply to a status the unique id of the original status is entered into here.

If I have missed anything out or need to explain better please let me know.

Cheers,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

You can try `SELECT DISTINCT` instead of `SELECT`

Comment: Hi Patrik, Thank you for your reply. Apologies I should have said in my first post that I have tried this. At the top I have tried SELECT DISTINCT (a.ra_id), and then rest of query but it returns the same results. Have you any further suggestions? Thank you Dan

Comment: Did you use DISTINCT for both SELECTs? Also, check that you need all the columns returned. The resultset is unique when using distinct, but the same original status might have other data in other columns.